# AmbiguousActionException when confirm e-mail in identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on a web service to manage user registration..

I don't understand because obtain this:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Test.Api.Controllers.AccountsController.ConfirmEmail (Test.Api)
> Test.Api.Controllers.AccountsController.ResetPassword (Test.Api)

This is my code

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

    var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userIdentity);
    var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(userIdentity.Id, token, Request.Scheme);
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm ",     $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");

    await _appDbContext.Customers.AddAsync(new Customer { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id, Location = model.Location });
    await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
}
```

I done a helper for buld the callbackUrl whit this code:

```
public static string EmailConfirmationLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string userId, string token, string scheme)
{
    return urlHelper.Action(
        action: nameof(AccountsController.ConfirmEmail),
        controller: "Accounts",
        values: new { userId, token },
        protocol: scheme);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
{
    if (userId == null || token == null)
    {
        return new BadRequestResult();
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
    }
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return new BadRequestResult();
    }
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "Account confermato","Il tuo account è stato confermato");
    return new OkObjectResult("Account confirmed");
}

public IActionResult ResetPassword(string code = null)
{
    if (code == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("A code must be supplied for password reset.");
    }
    var model = new ResetPasswordViewModel { Code = code };
    return View(model);
}
```

how is it possible that these two methods ( ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token) and ResetPassword(string code = null)) can create ambiguity? the two fime are different

Comment: Do you have a `[Route]` attribute on `AccountsController`? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: Yes this [Route("api/[controller]")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've indicated in the comments on your question that `AccountsController` is decorated with the following attribute:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

This means that your `ConfirmEmail` and `ResetPassword` actions are using the *same route*, which is simply `api/Accounts` in this case. When this route is loaded up in the browser, both actions are candidates for processing the request and so you get an error as described in your question.

In order to fix this, there are a few options:

1. Add `[Route("ConfirmEmail")]` to `ConfirmEmail` and `[Route("ResetPassword")]` to `ResetPassword` (similar to what you've done with the `Register` action).
2. Add `[Route("[action]")]` to both `ConfirmEmail` and `ResetPassword`, where `[action]` is a placeholder for the action name.
3. Remove `[Route("register")]` from your `Register` action and update the *controller's*  attribute to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`. You'd also need to remove `[Route(...)]` from any other actions you may have. Note that this approach is only viable if all your actions are routed according to the `api/[controller]/[action]` pattern.